# Appdesigner function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the Matlab command window, I am trying to open the "Appdesigner" function. Every time I launch the command, I receive an error message and a blank window that pops up. I am in deep need of help to fix it. thanks

Comment: Hello nathan, sharing the error message would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Alper, here's the message I receive:                                                                           Error using NaT (line 49)
Invalid default value for property 'Value' in class
'matlab.ui.control.DatePicker':
Error: File: datetime.m Line: 272 Column: 1
Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use
parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters.
There is multiple other errors but I cannot put them on here because of my characters allowance.

Comment: Hi there, you should [edit] your question and include all relevant information (i.e. error messages) there. Please also show **the exact code** you're running. Based on the information from your comment it can be anything from a misconfigured `uicontrol`, to a [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) issue.